# Probability measure on $\mathbb N$ such that $P(n \mathbb N) =1/n$ for all $n \ge 1$ cannot exist

Tags: probability-theory, integers

How to prove that $\mathbb N$ cannot be endowed to a probablity space $(\mathbb N, \mathcal F, P)$ such that for all integer $n \ge 1$ we have $$P(n \mathbb N)=\frac{1}{n}$$

I imagine that divergence of the harmonic series and inclusion-exclusion principle are good ingredients to be used... But I don't know how up to now!

Comment: Is $p$ not intended to be prime here?  I was working on the assumption that it was prime.  (If you meant to include composites, I would advise changing the letter).

Comment: I modified the question precising that $p$ is supposed to be prime.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Are you sure you want to restrict to $p$ prime? That makes my proof stop working.

Comment: No. You're right this is supposed to be true for all integer. I'll change $p$ for $n$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. Then the events $p_n\mathbb N$ are pairwise independent:

$$P(p_n\mathbb N \cap p_m\mathbb N)=P(p_np_m\mathbb N)=\frac 1{p_np_m}=P(p_n\mathbb N)P(p_m\mathbb N).$$

The sum of the reciprocals of the primes

$$\sum_n \frac 1{p_n}$$

[famously diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes). So, by the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result), the event that infinitely many of the events $p_n\mathbb N$ occur has probability one. But this cannot be satisfied, since no natural number divides by infinitely many primes. (Apart from $0$, but setting $P(0)=1$ is not a solution either.)

Comment: Impressive, I am curious to know if the problem can be solved also with an analytic approach.

Comment: @Oscar Cunningham Thanks for your answer! I let the question open for the time being to see if a more elementary proof can be found.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Good idea, I'd like to see a nicer proof too.

Comment: wonderful proof